# Monitor ionic app in production

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, monitoring

I have deployed my ionic app to the store.
Now I need to monitor and check how my app behaves on real user side :

My question is :

1. How can I collect the errors from the users
2. How can I monitor each action and state clicked ( to monitor how many times a user clicked a link )

Comment: You should have a backend service and logging every actions. Otherwise you can simply add [Google Analytics](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/googleAnalytics/).

Comment: google analytics is not suitable for errors stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to track events, I strongly recommend this tool [sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/)
free for low traffic with amazing dashboard and features.

here is an [article] giving alternatives 
[if u do not want sentry.io tool](https://medium.com/@jico/the-fine-art-of-javascript-error-tracking-bc031f24c659#.d7fp9gh0f)